# I kept getting 'ValueError: empty range for randrange()' when I import images into my little program

Tags: python

I use python3 and pycharm for my program and I'm not sure where is the problem when I get ValueError: empty range for randrange(), I've changed some setting for the game that I'm working on and it was fine at the beginning but since I imported the images for the program, it just kept running error.

```
line 317, in randrange
    raise ValueError("empty range for randrange() (%d, %d, %d)" % (istart, istop, width))
ValueError: empty range for randrange() (0, -59, -59)'
```

below is the code

```
# control sprite
import pygame
import random
import os

FPS = 80
RED = (255, 0, 0)
BLACK = (0, 0, 0)
GREEN = (0, 255, 0)
BLUE = (0, 0, 128)
WHITE = (255, 255, 255)
YELLOW = (255, 255, 0)
WIDTH = 500
HEIGHT = 600

pygame.init()
screen = pygame.display.set_mode((WIDTH, HEIGHT))
pygame.display.set_caption("Black Live Matters")
clock = pygame.time.Clock()

# pictures
background_img = pygame.image.load('wp3239685.jpg').convert()
player_img = pygame.image.load('plane.png').convert()
bullet_img = pygame.image.load('bullet.png').convert()
rock_img = pygame.image.load('rock0.png').convert()
#rock_imgs = [
    #pygame.image.load("rock0.png").convert(),
   # pygame.image.load("rock1.png").convert(),
   # pygame.image.load("rock2.png").convert(),
    #pygame.image.load("rock3.png").convert(),
#]


class Player(pygame.sprite.Sprite):
    def __init__(self):
        pygame.sprite.Sprite.__init__(self)
        self.image = pygame.transform.scale(player_img, (55,65))
        self.image.set_colorkey(BLACK)
        self.rect = self.image.get_rect()
        self.radius = 25
        # pygame.draw.circle(self.image, RED, self.rect.center, self.radius)

        self.rect.centerx = WIDTH / 2
        self.rect.bottom = HEIGHT - 10
        self.speedx = 8


    def update(self):
        key_pressed = pygame.key.get_pressed()
        if key_pressed[pygame.K_RIGHT]:
            self.rect.x += self.speedx
        if key_pressed[pygame.K_LEFT]:
            self.rect.x -= self.speedx

        if self.rect.right > WIDTH:
            self.rect.right = WIDTH
        if self.rect.left < 0:
            self.rect.left = 0

    def shoot (self):
        bullet = Bullet(self.rect.centerx, self.rect.top)
        all_sprites.add(bullet)
        bullets.add(bullet)

class Rock(pygame.sprite.Sprite):
    def __init__(self):
        pygame.sprite.Sprite.__init__(self)
        self.image_ori = rock_img
        self.image_ori.set_colorkey(BLACK)
        self.image = self.image_ori.copy()
        self.rect = self.image.get_rect()
        self.radius = self.rect.width * 0.85 / 2
        # pygame.draw.circle(self.image, RED, self.rect.center, self.radius)
        self.rect.x = random.randrange(0, WIDTH - self.rect.width)
        self.rect.y = random.randrange(-100, -40)
        self.speedy = random.randrange(2, 5)
        self.speedx = random.randrange(-3, 3)
        self.total_degree = 0
        self.rot_degree = 3

    def rotate(self):
        self.total_degree += self.rot_degree
        self.total_degree = self.total_degree % 360

        self.image = pygame.transform.rotate(self.image_ori, self.total_degree)

    def update(self):
        self.rotate()
        self.rect.y += self.speedy
        self.rect.x += self.speedx
        if self.rect.top > HEIGHT or self.rect.right < 0 or self.rect.left>WIDTH:
            self.rect.x = random.randrange(0, WIDTH - self.rect.width)
            self.rect.y = random.randrange(-100, -40)
            self.speedy = random.randrange(2, 10)
            self.speedx = random.randrange(-3, 3)

class Bullet(pygame.sprite.Sprite):
    def __init__(self, x, y):
        pygame.sprite.Sprite.__init__(self)
        self.image = pygame.transform.scale(bullet_img, (40, 50))
        self.image.set_colorkey(BLACK)
        self.rect = self.image.get_rect()
        self.rect.centerx = x
        self.rect.bottom = y
        self.speedy = -5
        # self.rotate = 2


    # def rotate(self):
       #  self.image = pygame.transform.rotate(self.image, self.rot_degree)
    def update(self):
        # self.rotate()
        self.rect.y += self.speedy
        if self.rect.bottom < 0:
            self.kill()


all_sprites = pygame.sprite.Group()
player = Player()
rocks = pygame.sprite.Group()
bullets = pygame.sprite.Group()
all_sprites.add(player)
for i in range(8):
    r = Rock()
    all_sprites.add(r)
    rocks.add(r)


# game loop
running = True
while running:
    clock.tick(FPS)
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            running = False
        elif event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
            if event.key == pygame.K_SPACE:
                player.shoot()

    #update
    all_sprites.update()
    hits = pygame.sprite.groupcollide(rocks, bullets, True, True)
    for hit in hits:
        r = Rock()
        all_sprites.add(r)
        rocks.add(r)

    hits = pygame.sprite.spritecollide(player, rocks, False, pygame.sprite.collide_circle)
    if hits:
        running = False


    # display
    screen.fill(BLACK)
    screen.blit(background_img, (0, 0))
    all_sprites.draw(screen)
    pygame.display.update()

pygame.quit()
```

Comment: By reading your code I suppose your attribute `self.rect.width` is greater than your `WIDTH` variable. So your `randrange` function is run with unexpected values (randrange(start, stop, step),  `start` has to be less than `stop`). In my opinion, your image is greater than your `WIDTH` so.

Comment: Please trim your code to make it easier to find your problem. Follow these guidelines to create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Answer (score 0):

The error usually is raised when you first value greater then the second value. The error says you used `randrange(0, -59, -59)` and the Number `0` is bigger than the number `-59` try switching the Numbers like this and it should do the thing:

```
randrange(-59, -59, 0)
```

Answer (score 0):

If second argument is not greater than first argument You have to set step to negative number, like in this example:

```
random.randrange(0, -59, -1)
```

From docs

Return a randomly selected element from range(start, stop, step).